# git push branches in same namespace

Tags: git

I would like to push multiple branches with a similar naming or equal namespace, like so:

`git push backup issues/*`

This 'fails' with `Everything up-to-date`, although there are changes. Each branch pushed indivually works, so does the --all option, but I would like to only push the relevant branches in a post-commit hook.

How can this be done?

Comment: What is a "namespace", i.e. what is the mapping logic of "this commit" and "which branches to push"? Do you only want to push your current branch to a single branch, with a matching name, or is it something more complex?

Comment: Here the namespace would be 'issues', one might also call it a folder because that is what it does in many git gui clients. There are several numbered tickets in our ticket system and the branch names would reflect that, e.g. issues/8184-important-change

Comment: But when you're working on a branch, and commit something, that commit only exists in your checked out branch. So, pushing the currently active branch (if it matches "issues/*") would suffice, right? We know that no other branches has this new commit. Edit: you may want to push on other hooks as well, see `post-merge` and `post-rewrite` too: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: Good point. The idea was derived from the --all option that is in place at the moment but pushes way too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try

```
git branch | grep "issues/*" | xargs git push
```

If you want to abbreviate, you could try to create an alias `mypush`

```
git config --global alias.mypush 'git branch | grep "issues/*" | xargs git push'
```

You might need to play with `'` or `"`.

Comment: This works, thank you. But does it mean there is no git way to do it?

Comment: @user2851662 you put that code in `.git/hooks/post-commit` (and put a shebang in it), and make the file executable.

Comment: Always consider using `git for-each-ref` instead of `git branch` or `git tag` for listing branch or tag names when scripting. In this case, `git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/heads/issues` would get you the same output without any danger of copying an asterisk `*` (and no need for `grep` here).